# Why am I getting 404 GET /index.html when I use lite-server in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, deployment, lite-server

I have an Angular project which I cannot deploy so I decided to use lite-server to see what's wrong. But when I run lite-server in my terminal, I get the following errors:

```
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
21.09.26 17:17:05 404 GET /index.html
21.09.26 17:17:06 404 GET /favicon.ico
21.09.26 17:20:21 404 GET /index.html
```

This is my scripts object in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve the application with `lite-server` you need to build it first. So run `npm run build`. This will put the built application by default in `dist/<app_name>` folder. After that `lite-server` should be called with `--baseDir` parameter which lets `lite-server` know, where the built application is. So I suggest to update the `dev` script to `"dev": "lite-server --baseDir=\"dist/<app_name>\""`.

If you need to watch the build output, you can define an npm script with `ng build --watch` content. This could run in the first terminal, and in the second one the `lite-server`.

Comment: Salute! @milan-tenk , I accidentally had `'dist/<app_name>'` instead of `\"dist/<app_name>\"`